# Maple style workbooks in MathCAD?

Tags: project, maple, mathcad

I hope to use MathCAD for some broad (but simple) engineering computations but it doesn't seem to have the concept of workbooks (like Maple).  How does one combine worksheets, libraries, data in MathCAD, along with all the other facilities available with the Maple workbook file format?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work in Maple, but if we talk about Mathcad 15, I think, there isn't special form to store worksheets, libraries and data in file.

If you need link libraries with special functions (by UserEFI), they well be avaliable from all worksheets.

For information, in my opinion, in most cases, you need to use Mathcad 15, because Mathcad Prime 6.0 still very cut version with few advantages (x64, matrices with values with different units).